# Using physical constants with boost

Tags: c++, boost

I'd like to define some constants in a c++ program. The excellent boost library has them predefined, and I like to assign my constants these values, e.g. something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/codata/electromagnetic_constants.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    double electron_charge = boost::units::si::constants::codata::e;

    std::cout << electron_charge << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But this does not work since boost's e is not of type `double` but of type `value_type`. How can I access the value in double precision?

Comment: You probably need to use `boost::units::quantity<>` rather than `double`. All of the purpose is to make units type safe.

Comment: But what if all you want is the constant and don't need the type safety?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think that's what `value()` function of this class is for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to divide the electric charge of the electron by the electric charge unit: Coulomb:

```
double electron_charge = boost::units::si::constants::codata::e / boost::units::si::coulomb;
```

Comment: Nice. It makes it unitless and in the same time documents the unit.